# WordPress and jQuery: I just can't get jScrollPane working! (Or, I just can't get jQuery to work!)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jscrollpane

I've been using WordPress for years and have never, through all my tons and tons of reading, been able to get any custom jQuery scripts working.

Today's is jScrollPane: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ . One of the best scripts ever made for pixel-perfect web designers who have to have EVERYTHING look just right.

I'm using the latest version of WordPress (3.4.1) and the Whiteboard Framework (theme). I do not have a site to link to, as I am building the site offline using XAMPP.

Here is what I know:

In my header.php, inside my  tags and below wp_head(), I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mousewheel"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
```

I have jquery.jscrollpane.css in a directory called "css" in the root of my theme, and jquery.jscrollpane.min.js and jquery.mousewheel.js in a directory called "js" in the root of my theme.

Right above  in my footer.php, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function()
{
jQuery('#main').jScrollPane();
});
</script>
```

Currently I have nothing in my functions.php.

I know nothing about jQuery. Nothing at all, except for various tidbits I've read about WordPress and no_conflict modes, registering and enqueuing script, and various other things that have been repeated countless times, but which do not seem to help me no matter what I try...

Countless sites of reading-- many dozens. Countless hours... WordPress ought to have something in the backend to make jQuery much easier. I'm just so very sick of it all. Doesn't help that I haven't had much to eat or much rest since I started trying to figure this thing out...

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

**Update:** I tried what martinCzerwi said, adding that code to my functions.php, and deleting the  stuff from my . I got an error message in Firebug's Web Developer:

```
"Error: TypeError: jQuery("#main").jScrollPane is not a function"
```

This pertains to my site's footer.php, which includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function()
{
    jQuery('#main').jScrollPane('refresh');
});
</script>
```

I know just a little bit about PHP; not enough to help me, though.

---

I did what martinCzerwi said. I added that to my functions.php and removed the stuff inside my . After fixing the URL's to my files inside the functions.php, it worked. I finally got jQuery working in a WordPress site!

Big thanks to all, especially martinCzerwi!

Comment: Are you getting any specific javascript error messages? Also, you say that your `functions.php` file is empty...does that mean you aren't including jQuery?

Comment: Why aren't you using [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to load your scripts and styles?
Do they even load if you include them with relative script tags? If you had a blog on `http://example.com/` your script tags point to `http://example.com/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min` which is not where your theme resides.

Comment: @martinCzerwi Yes, you can include scripts directly in the header the way that he is if you're careful to make the path relative to your base WordPress location...but you pretty much never should. Using `wp_enqueue_script` is always the way to go in my opinion, especially on commonly used scripts like jQuery. If you don't, you'll inevitably run into conflicts or path issues.

Comment: @Chaser324 I tried what martinCzerwi said, adding that code to my functions.php, and deleting the stuff from my . I got an error message in Firebug's Web Developer:

"Error: TypeError: jQuery("#main").jScrollPane is not a function"

This pertains to my site's footer.php, which includes:

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function()
{
    jQuery('#main').jScrollPane('refresh');
});
</script>

I know just a little bit about PHP; not enough to help me, though.

Comment: @MTPrower Could it be possible we both missed out on the typos in the filenames? Is the file really called `jquery.jscrollpane.min` without `.js`?
The error message seems to me, like the scrollpane script was not loaded ;) If the filenames are wrong, please change them and try.

Comment: Yeah, there's one of two things happening. Either you have a filename/path issue that's causing the jscrollpane code to not load (should be pretty easy to check if the file loaded using FireBug or similar dev tool), or those scripts are getting loaded after that code that you inserted in the footer. To avoid that, I'd recommend you throw that little bit of stuff you have in the footer into a `.js` file and enqueue it in your `functions.php` file after jQuery and jscrollpane.

Comment: I misnamed the references to the .js files. I named them correctly and now it works!!

Comment: Congratulations, you've been able to get a custom jQuery script working ;)

Comment: If you found Martin's answer helpful, you can accept it by clicking the green check mark next to it when the system permits. This shows future visitors that his answer helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

Using the WordPress given functions I'd recommend instead of using script tags with relative paths, you include this in your `functions.php`:

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts_and_styles () {
  // Enqueue scripts
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-mwheel', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.mousewheel.js', array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-scrollpane', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-mwheel'));

  // Enqueue styles
  wp_enqueue_style('jquery-scrollpane-style', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/css/jquery.jscrollpane.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts_and_styles');
```

Having this function registered, you can drop your script tags from `<head>`. The function will automatically include your styles and scripts, and even include jQuery on the fly, as long as you're calling `wp_head();` before your `</head>`-Tag. Its using absolute paths, because relative paths will break, when you use a different permalink-setting, than the default one.

Comment: I did this. I found an error in Firefox's Web Developer, pertaining to my code below </body>:

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function()
    {
    jQuery('#main').jScrollPane('refresh');
    });
    </script>

"Error: TypeError: jQuery("#main").jScrollPane is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to `functions.php` to dereigster any jQuery scripts and have your own.. But this won't combat any hard-coded includes from poorly coded plugins.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Alternatively, you could use a jQuery conflict mode, and use it as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var k = jQuery.noConflict();
k(function() {
      k('#main').jScrollPane();
   });
</script>
```

Please make sure you have `<? wp_footer(); ?>` in your footer if any plugins rely on libraries being included.

Comment: You might want to use the newest version: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js`

Comment: I agree, he `might` want to, but I doubt it would break my answer.

Comment: No, ofcourse it doesn't break your answer down. It was just a hint. :)

Answer (score 0):

### It would seem to me that you are not linking correctly **or** that you didn't include jQuery itself.

---

It would be logical if your site structure was like this:

```
root\wp-content\themes\your-theme
```

And you would have put a map there in which you place your JavaScript and possibly also a seperate map for additional CSS, like so:

```
root\wp-content\themes\your-theme\js
root\wp-content\themes\your-theme\css
```

Then, you want to link to these and it might sound logical to just put this (as you did) in your header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mousewheel"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
```

Wordpress has a function to get the stylesheet directory. You can use that! To echo this directory,  use this:

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>
```

So, above links would result in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.mousewheel"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
```

If the theme that you are using does not include jQuery itself, add this line of code, but make sure it's loaded before any other JavaScript code (just to make sure you aren't missing any scripts that use jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's often recommended to first load your stylesheets and then your scripts. So everything together would result in this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.mousewheel"></script>
```